# Function Pointer inside Class (expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type)

Tags: c++, class, function-pointers, pointer-to-member, member-functions

I want to use different functions depending on the input to calculate the output.
but it says: (expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type)

int (TestClass::* Gate_Func)(vector); <<== this is the function I initiated.

and then here: Gate_Func = &TestClass::AND;
I can reference to the AND function with Gate_Func

but why
output = Gate_Func(InputArr);
this one has an error:
C++ expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
class TestClass {
public:
    int AND(vector<int> inputarr) {
        return (inputarr[0] == 1 && inputarr[1] == 1);
    }

    int OR(vector<int> inputarr) {
        return (inputarr[0] == 1 || inputarr[1] == 1);
    }

    int NOT(vector<int> inputarr) {
        if (inputarr[0] != 0) return 0;
        else return 1;
    }

    int (TestClass::* Gate_Func)(vector<int>);

    TestClass(int ChooseFunction, vector<int> inputarr) {
        InputArr = inputarr;
        switch (ChooseFunction)
        {
        case 1:
            Gate_Func = &TestClass::AND;
            break;
        case 2:
            Gate_Func = &TestClass::OR;
            break;
        case 3:
            Gate_Func = &TestClass::NOT;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    void calculation() {
        output = Gate_Func(InputArr); //C++ expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type
    }
    vector<int> InputArr;
    int output = 2;
    void printOutput() { cout << output << endl; }
};

int main() {
    vector<int> input = { 1, 1 };

    TestClass obj(1, input);

    obj.printOutput();
}
```

Oh! I see, thank you guys, so when I use 'this', it's basically like calling the object of the Class and I have to call the function from that object!

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
class TestClass {
public:
    int AND(vector<int> inputarr) {
        return (inputarr[0] == 1 && inputarr[1] == 1);
    }

    int OR(vector<int> inputarr) {
        return (inputarr[0] == 1 || inputarr[1] == 1);
    }

    int NOT(vector<int> inputarr) {
        if (inputarr[0] != 0) return 0;
        else return 1;
    }

    int (TestClass::* Gate_Func)(vector<int>);

    TestClass(int ChooseFunction, vector<int> inputarr) {
        InputArr = inputarr;
        switch (ChooseFunction)
        {
        case 1:
            Gate_Func = &TestClass::AND;
            break;
        case 2:
            Gate_Func = &TestClass::OR;
            break;
        case 3:
            Gate_Func = &TestClass::NOT;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        calculation();
    }

    void calculation() {
        output = (this->*Gate_Func)(InputArr); //C++ expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type
    }
    vector<int> InputArr;
    int output = 2;
    void printOutput() { cout << output << endl; }
};

int main() {
    vector<int> input = { 1, 1 };

    TestClass obj(1, input);

    obj.printOutput();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions `AND`, `OR`, and `NOT` are non-static member functions. They can only be called when an instance of their class is supplied.

`Gate_Func` is a pointer to non-static member function. It can point to a non-static member function such as `AND`, `OR`, or `NOT`. In order to invoke it, you must supply an instance of the class (just as you would have to do in order to call `AND`, `OR`, or `NOT` directly). You also need to supply the arguments to the function.

This is done using a special syntax:

```
(p->*Gate_Func)(InputArr);
```

Here, `p` is a pointer to the instance on which to invoke the function, and `InputArr` is the argument. If there are multiple arguments, they are separated by commas just like in an ordinary function call.

If you can't remember this syntax, you can also do `std::invoke(Gate_Func, p, InputArr)`. (The instance pointer `p` goes before all the arguments.)

In your case, I suspect you want to invoke the function on the current instance. You can do this by using `this` (e.g., `(this->*Gate_Func)(InputArr)`).

Comment: yeah, but even if I add static in front of both: 
"static int AND(vector<int> inputarr)"
and
"static int (TestClass::* Gate_Func)(vector<int>)"

it throws another error:
"a value of type cannot be assigned to an entity of type"

Comment: A static class method cannot be assigned to a pointer-to-member.  So you would have to change the type of `Gate_Func` from `int (TestClass::*)(vector<int>)` to `int (*)(vector<int>)`

Answer (score 1):

A pointer to a member function requires a pointer to an instance of the type (`this`) as well as the arguments. The syntax for providing it is fairly ugly:

```
(this->*GateFunc)(InputArr)
```

If you have access to C++17, use `std::invoke`:

```
std::invoke(GateFunc, this, InputArr)
```